# Relationship between averages of two variables and the slope of their regression line

Tags: regression

Suppose the least-squares regression line for $y$ and $x$ is $y = kx$. Given that $0 < k < 1$, can we say anything about the means of $y$ and $x$? Can we infer that $\bar{y} < \bar{x}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall,
the least squares coefficient
for $y = kx$
is
$k = \frac{\sum xy}{\sum x^2}
$.

This doesn't say anything
about the means of $x$ and $y$,
but does imply
imformation about
the means of
$xy$ and $x^2$.